# Why most files like jpeg or pdf don't use just ASCII characters for encoding?

Tags: encoding

Whenever we try to open a JPEG or PDF file with any text editor we find strange symbols other than ASCII. Isn't ASCII most efficient because of less space consumption by limited number of possible characters available.

[image: File opened in Terminal]

I was working with a database file in Linux with plocate and I found something similar.

Comment: Using ASCII would use 33% *more* disk space.

Comment: ASCII is for encoding text. Why would storing non-text data be related to ASCII at all? Just because you *can* try to interpret an image file as text, doesn't mean that doing so tells you anything worthwhile about the file.

Comment: Better question is, why would they? Look at JPEG in HxD or some hex editor and you'll find the image data is tightly packed, high entropy data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't Ascii most efficient because of less space consumption by limited number of possible characters available.

Not at all. Where did you get that idea from?

ASCII chars are 7bits long, but hardware doesn't support storing 7bits items, so ASCII is stored with 8bits, the first bit being always 0. Furthermore, ASCII includes a number of control characters that can cause issues in some situation. Therefore, the most prominent ASCII encoding (base 64) uses only 6bits. This mean that in order to encode 3 bytes (3*8 = 24 bits) of data you need 4 ASCII characters (4* 6 = 24). Those 4 ASCII characters are then stored using 4 bytes on disk. Hence, converting a file to ASCII increases disk usage by 33%.

You can test this with the `base64` command:

```
base64 pic.jpg > b64_jpeg.txt
ls -lh pic.jpg b64_jpeg.txt
```

Of course, you could try to use another ASCII encoding than the standard base64 and use all 7 bits available in ASCII. You would still get only 7bits of data per bytes on disk, thus have a +14% disk usage increase for the same data.

Comment: Technically [ASCII specifies a 7-bit encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690159/is-ascii-code-in-matter-of-fact-7-bit-or-8-bit). It's just that everyone and their dog uses 8-bit bytes so the 7-bit encoding is transferred in 8 bits per character instead.

Answer (score 0):

All modern storage uses 8-bit bytes. ASCII is an obsolete 7 bits standard, so it would take 8/7th as much storage (+14%).

Comment: Obsolete?!?! [Hardly](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):  "This specification defines a number of standardized methods that are commonly used in HTTP, as outlined by the following table.  By convention, standardized methods are defined in all-uppercase US-ASCII letters."

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing to do with number of bits as such, all binary files are the same 2 bits (true or false) what makes an image or PDF look different to Ascii text is that each single byte of bits is compressed in groups for optimal efficiency. Those symbolic strings are perhaps ASCII but compressed to about 10%.

Take a pdf of a graph as follows

- ASCII = 394,132 bytes
- ZIP    =      88,367 bytes
- PDF   =   75,753 bytes
- DocX =   32,940 bytes its text and lines (there are no images)

Take an image

- PNG = 265,490 bytes
- ZIP = 265,028 bytes
- PDF = 220,152 bytes
- PDF as ASCII = 3,250,970 bytes

```
3 0 obj
<</Length 3120001/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 640/Height 800/BitsPerComponent 8/SMask 4 0 R/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Filter/ASCIIHexDecode>>
stream
9cb6c79cb6c79cb6c79cb6c79db7c89db7c89db7c89fb7c9a0b8caa1b8caa1b8
caa1b8caa2b9cba2b9cba2b9cba2b9cba3bacba3bacaa4bbcba4bbcba6bccca7
...to infinity and beyond
```

So why is as ASCII image bigger than all the rest is because those `9cb6c7` can be tokenised as 4 x `9cb6c7` , 3 x `9db7c8` , etc , that's roughly how RunLengthEncoding would work, but zip is better than that.

So PARTS of a pdf may be compressed (needing slower decompression to view) in a zip style of coding (used for lossless fonts and bitmaps), whilst others may keep their optimal native photographic lossy compression (like jpeg). Overall for PDF parsing a higher percentage needs to be 8 bit ANSI (compatible with uni-coding or variable per platform) or 7bit ASCII for simplistic parsing.

Short answer compression is the means to reduce time of transmission or amount of storage resources. However decompression adds an overhead so is slower than RAW ASCII to display as graphics. Avoid exotic wavelets in a PDF where most objects need fast decompression.